# How can I reduce space between images when using <figure>?

Tags: html, css

How can I adjust the space between images when using `<figure>`? I want to reduce the space, but for some reason I just can't get it it to budge.

I want 3 images to sit on one row, but because I can't reduce the space between images to allow them to fit comfortably in the div box, the 3rd is wrapping and sitting below the first two

```css
.container3 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container3 figure {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container3">
<figure>
  <img class="image" height="200px" width="300px" src="/images/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="berry blitz">
  <figcaption>
    Fall Berry Blitz Tea
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img class="image" height="200px" width="300px" src="/images/img-spiced-rum.jpg" alt="spiced rum">
  <figcaption>
    Spiced Rum Tea
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img class="image" height="200px" width="300px" src="/images/img-donut.jpg" alt="donut">
  <figcaption>
    Seasonal Donuts
  </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: add `display:flex;` to `.container3` css

Comment: Are you not simply talking about the `margin`? Something like `margin: 0;` will completely remove it. Depending on your browser `margin: 8px;` could half it.

Answer (score 1):

Figure has a margin of 16px applied. You can adjust the margin, if it is that, what you want:

```css
.container3 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.container3 figure {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container3">
  <figure>
    <img class="image" height="200px" width="300px" src="/images/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="berry blitz">
    <figcaption>
      Fall Berry Blitz Tea
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img class="image" height="200px" width="300px" src="/images/img-spiced-rum.jpg" alt="spiced rum">
    <figcaption>
      Spiced Rum Tea
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img class="image" height="200px" width="300px" src="/images/img-donut.jpg" alt="donut">
    <figcaption>
      Seasonal Donuts
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

If you want to distribute the available space evenly between the images, you can use flexbox and use `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
.container3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.container3 figure {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container3">
  <figure>
    <img class="image" height="200px" width="300px" src="/images/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="berry blitz">
    <figcaption>
      Fall Berry Blitz Tea
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img class="image" height="200px" width="300px" src="/images/img-spiced-rum.jpg" alt="spiced rum">
    <figcaption>
      Spiced Rum Tea
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img class="image" height="200px" width="300px" src="/images/img-donut.jpg" alt="donut">
    <figcaption>
      Seasonal Donuts
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

I've added another snippet based on OP's comment:

```css
.container {
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.row figure {
  background: #DEDEDE;
  /* or width */
  flex-basis: calc(100% * 1/3);
  /* you may use max-width: 100px; to limit the size */
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-3">
    <figure>Fig. 1</figure>
    <figure>Fig. 2</figure>
    <figure>Fig. 3</figure>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-2">
    <figure>Fig. 4</figure>
    <figure>Fig. 5</figure>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-1">
    <figure>Fig. 6</figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: without flex, you could use `text-align-last`  **for info only** . but flex is done for this, and of course that margin reset on figure.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I think I must have been adding margin: 0; to the parent container in my frustration. How can I make two images below share the same spacing as the top 3  when using justify-content: space-around? I've added 2 more, but they have a lot more space due to their being more space without a 3rd pic on the second row

Comment: You must set some boundaries: Either you have to specify dimensions for the figure elements or you can let flexbox take care of the spacing and sizing (with flex-basis, flex-shrink, flex-grow). In the example I've provided just now, you may add multiple rows and you can treat each row individually, if you like. If the example does not help, you have to be more specific how it should behave. I've just made some assumptions.

Comment: I have a flex container 1000px in width with 3 inline images each 300px width on the top row and 2 inline images same dimensions underneath. Margin: 0; and Justify-content: space-around work perfectly for the top row, 100px of spacing to use. But with only 2 images on the 2nd row I have 400px left over which makes space-around display much larger gaps than the top row. What is the simplest way to cause the second row to have the same spacing as the top row to keep uniformity?

Comment: @Hanzo-Hasashi You cannot do it like that for n-ary items on multiple rows. You can add rows (containers with n-items) and for the second row you center it and set a max-width for the figures. There is also `space-around` that can be used along with the other flex-grow and flex-shrink properties. Have a look at the third snipped I've added. Does it do what you want? You can make it fit 100% on every row, but this would scale the figures - you can also do that if you want.
If this still does not do it for you ... add a drawing of your design to your question.

Comment: Got it fixed. All I had to do was add 166.5px margin to the outter side of both items. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Hanzo-Hasashi I'd probably not do that: "Half-Pixels" (there is no such thing) are up to the browser i.e. the rendering engine will decide how it will be treated (rounding errors). This could lead to some weird visual bugs. If you don't want to use flexbox - try to use a container div for the second row and add: `margin: 0 auto` and set a fixed width for the container i.e. 2*width of a figure + 1 gap would be the width.

Answer (score 0):

inline-block elements have the "funny" way of including the whitespace after the tag. You have 2 possibilities to remove the whitespace:

1. As @Breezer suggested add `display: flex;` to the parent-container.
2. remove the whitespace in html after each figure like so:

```
    <figure>
        <img class="image" height="200px" width="300px" src="/images/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="berry blitz">
        <figcaption>
            Fall Berry Blitz Tea
        </figcaption>
    </figure><figure>
        <img class="image" height="200px" width="300px" src="/images/img-spiced-rum.jpg" alt="spiced rum">
        <figcaption>
            Spiced Rum Tea
        </figcaption>
    </figure><figure>
        <img class="image" height="200px" width="300px" src="/images/img-donut.jpg" alt="donut">
        <figcaption>
            Seasonal Donuts
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
```

Comment: you can also set the container's font-size to 0. it will get rig of the magic white space

Comment: @mok_ku nice, learned something new ^^ but means that you'll have to set a specific font-size for e.g. the figcaption.

Comment: In this case, I guess you need to set on the <figure> , so the magic white space will not appear between the image and the figcaption

Comment: Sorry, it should be the .container3 that need to set for the font-size: 0, so that the inline-block <figure> will not have white space

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: flex` on the container should be enough.

Also, the `<img>` tag expects unitless `width` and `height` attributes (without "px"):

```css
.container3 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container3 figure {
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container3">
<figure>
  <img class="image" height="200" width="300" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt="berry blitz">
  <figcaption>
    Fall Berry Blitz Tea
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img class="image" height="200" width="300" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt="spiced rum">
  <figcaption>
    Spiced Rum Tea
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img class="image" height="200" width="300" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt="donut">
  <figcaption>
    Seasonal Donuts
  </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```